# Prevent Switch to List View on WindowResize

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar with Oracle APEX.  By default when the window resizes (around 715px) the View mode automatically changes to List View.  I want to keep the same view unless the user clicks on the List view.

How can I prevent the automatic view change on WindowResize?